# For $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ i.i.d. with Poisson distribution, and $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i$, how to show $E(Y_1 \mid S_n) = \frac1nS_n$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$ are iid observations from a Poisson distribution. I am trying to show why:

$$\mathbb E\left(Y_1 \;\;\middle| \;\;\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right) = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$$

I know that one way is to directly go to the infinite summation, but was wondering if there was an easier way to get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** By symmetry, the conditional expectation has the same value if you replace $Y_1$ with $Y_i$ on the left-hand side. Use this and the equation $E[X \mid X]=X$ almost surely.

Note that this approach does need the fact that the random variables are independent and identically distributed (or more generally, [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables)) for $E[Y_1 \mid \sum Y_i] = E[Y_j \mid \sum Y_i]$ to hold. The fact that the distribution is Poisson does not play a significant role - the proof works for any other distribution with finite first moment.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: So for this problem we only needed the "identically distributed" part and not the independent part?

Comment: These are both necessary. If the random variables are not independent, you can't replace $X_1$ with an atbitrary $X_i$. The Poisson part however is unnecessary.

Comment: @Did I have added a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, if you won't mind, could you explain more in detail where dependency would break down the relation? I can only see it through independency implying exchangeability and hence a permutation of the indices holding but would setting $Y_1 = 2Y_2$ be a valid example of the necessity of independence? Since $E[Y_1 \mid \sum Y_i] =2E[Y_2 \mid \sum Y_i]\neq E[Y_2 \mid \sum Y_i]$?

Comment: Your example doesn't work, as you don't have identical distributions (unless $Y_2 = 0$ almost surely, but then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent again). For a counter-example, let $Y_1 \sim U(\{0, 1, 2\})$ and $Y_2 = Y_1 + 1 \pmod 3$. Then $E[X_1 \mid X_1 + X_2 = 1] = 0$ while $E[X_2 \mid X_1 + X_2 = 1] = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your example, just as a side note, for your two conditional expectations, how did you get that they are $0$ and $1$? Is it just by recognizing that if the sum is $1$, then $X_1$ must have originated at $0$ and $X_2$ can only be $1$ due to additivity? Or is there a more formal way to see it? Thanks!

Comment: I just wrote down a table that shows which value $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_1+X_2$ assume. In this case, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are measurable with respect to $X_1 + X_2$, so it is easy to determine the conditional expectation.

Comment: @user321627 FYI, Dominik's example might be the *minimal* example of two identically distributed random variables that are not exchangeable. (+1)